# CentOS 7 + bcache

Tags: centos7

bcache was rolled into the 3.10 mainline kernel. I've just installed CentOS 7 with `3.10.0-123.4.4.el7.x86_64`. However, after creating the cache devices I realised they were't attached. Turns out `/sys/fs/bcache` doesn't exist - ie it's not enabled in the kernel, but why? I believe it's enabled by default in Ubuntu/etc...

Comment: Because: Redhat. Sometimes they strip mainline kernel feature out of the distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7 was forked from Fedora 19, and in that release bcache support was minimal, experimental and buggy. It currently isn't [planned to be complete until Fedora 22](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/SSD_cache). As a general rule, Red Hat does not ship features in RHEL which aren't production-ready, even as a technology preview.

If I were to guess, I would expect to see this appear in RHEL as a technology preview sometime around 7.2, or 7.3, or perhaps even 7.4, depending on how development progresses -- and importantly, depending on whether Red Hat customers ask for it... or more likely I'm totally wrong.

[Red Hat's current stance on bcache](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/72133) is:

> bcache is another option available in the Fedora 22 Linux distribution and merged into the upstream Linux kernel. It is not currently viewed by Red Hat as Enterprise ready as a supported technology.

Red Hat instead supports dm-cache and lvmcache as of RHEL 6.7 and 7.1.

Answer (score -1):

By default, centos 7 doesn't compile with bcache. You should compile and insert the bcache module manually. Then /sys/fs/bcache will show up.
See http://10sa.com/sql_stories/?p=1052